# MSBuild compile error "resgen.exe" .Net FX 3.5 Tools

Tags: .net, windows-7, frameworks, msbuild, winapi

Im trying to compile a project made in VS2012 in Windows 7 x64.

Trying to compile it in a virtualmachine with Windows 7 x86 and .Net framework 4.0 installed using MsBuild 4.0 but I get this error about "resgen.exe" and netfx tools 3.5:

```
"C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Temp\Virtuosa Game Packer\Virtuosa Game P
acker.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Temp\Virtuosa Game Packer\Extractor.vbpro
j" (default target) (2) ->
(CoreResGen target) ->
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(2291,5
): error MSB3091: Task failed because "resgen.exe" was not found, or the correc
t Microsoft Windows SDK is not installed. The task is looking for "resgen.exe"
in the "bin" subdirectory beneath the location specified in the InstallationFol
der value of the registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft S
DKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFx35Tools-x86. You may be able to solve the problem
 by doing one of the following:  1) Install the Microsoft Windows SDK.  2) Inst
all Visual Studio 2010.  3) Manually set the above registry key to the correct
location.  4) Pass the correct location into the "ToolPath" parameter of the ta
sk. [C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Temp\Virtuosa Game Packer\Extractor.v
bproj]

    5 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

My question is what requisites about Framework will need another machine to compile the project?

If I install the NetFX Tools 3.5 in that virtual machina then I can compile the project?

Where I can download the NetFXTools 3.5 x86? (Really I can't find it in Google)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the errormessage states you can copy resgen from your computer to somwhere on the vm and change the registry to point to the correct path.

Comment: where do you find it though?

Comment: You find ResGen.exe in the install directory of the Windows SDK on your host machine (e.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin). You can copy this to your VM.

Comment: I have the same problem. I just downloaded and installed Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (from the link below), and the bin folder of the latest SDK ( C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin ) definitely does NOT contain resgen.exe

Anywhere else I could find it ?

Comment: @wonko79 what do you mean by `VM` ?

Comment: VM == "Virtual Machine"

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is to install only the .net development tools from the windows SDK.
Use the web installer deselect all, select only "Tools" under Dot net framework development.

Web installer for windows sdk:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279