# Windows SDK 7.1 Setup failure

Tags: .net, windows, sdk, .net-4.0, installation

I am trying to install Windows SDK for Windows 7 with .NET Framework 4 but when I open the setup I receive an error:

> Some Windows SDK components require the RTM .NET Framework 4. Setup
>   detected a pre-release version of .NET Framework 4. If you continue
>   with Setup, these components will not be installed. If you want to
>   install these components, click Cancel, then install the .NET
>   Framework 4 from https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=187668 and
>   then rerun Setup.
>
> Click OK to continue.

When I went to install the .NET Framework 4 it appears a message saying that there is already the .NET Framework 4 on my PC:

> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4 is already part of the operating
>   system. No need to install the .NET Framework 4 redistributable. [More
>   information](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=164207).
>
> An equal or higher version of the .NET Framework 4 has already been
>   installed on the computer.

I don't know what to do anymore. I am using Windows 10 Enterprise (x64).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install windows SDK 7.1 on windows 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091593/cannot-install-windows-sdk-7-1-on-windows-10)

Comment: Nowadays, the link they provide is broken and just redirects to the generic .NET page `>:(`

Answer (score 110, accepted):

With Windows 10 x64, the setup is [blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322920/32453) by:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\Version
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client\Version
```

Change both values temporarily to `4.0.30319` and the setup will let you continue. Make sure you edit the registry with elevated privileges, otherwise you will not be allowed to change the values.

Comment: On Windows 7 (32 bit) these keys can be found at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\.

Comment: I tried all the above, yours did the trick! Is it required to reset the verion values to the before?

Comment: @linusg: you'd better do it.

Comment: If you get an error like 'Error writing the value’s new contents.', you don't have permissions to change the value. See this guide to change that: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/take-full-permissions-control-edit-protected-registry-keys/

Comment: I changed both values and still get the same error when trying to install `dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe`.  This registry fix does not solve the issue for me.

Comment: @ArvoBowen : The fix is for installing SDK 7.1. not the .NET Framework 4. The fix is for fooling the SDK to think the already installed framework is an older version to allow the installation to continue.

Comment: @Jarno I also found that these keys were at the location you list despite being on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: This did unblock the installer at an early point in the install process, but didn't allow full install. MandM's solution, in combination with this one, and uninstalling all .NET Frameworks >= 4.0, and reinstalling just 4.0, seemed to work for me.

Comment: I tried the process to unblock it. But, it didn't work. So, in the end; I installed this version for Azure. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/blainbar/2013/07/24/step-by-step-using-a-self-signed-private-certificate-makecert-exe-with-windows-azure-backup-vault-and-windows-server-2012-r2/

Comment: This fix prevents the initial block. After some time the installation is stalled.On examining the log file, i am getting the following error.
//Error 1329. A file that is required cannot be installed because the cabinet file %temp%/SDKSetup\WinSDKSamples\WinSDKSamples_amd64\cab3.cab is not digitally signed.// How to fix this?

Answer (score 27):

I had to uninstall the following:

- "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable"
- "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable"

Before installing the Windows 7.1 SDK, and the [install package](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) reinstalls those two during installation.

Comment: If error message persists despite this workaround, just click OK and proceed with installation. The installation will succeed this time..

Comment: I have the same problem, and I did install "compatible" redistribution of the MVC++2010, as per Microsoft article here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2717426 
but there are still part of the SDK that refuses to install properly. In particular, I cannot managed to install resgen.exe 
I may have to uninstall 4.6 completely as proposed in the other comment, and revert to version 4 of .NET

Note, this is link to this other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516139/msbuild-compile-error-resgen-exe-net-fx-3-5-tools

Answer (score 18):

In order to deal with this problem, I uninstalled my `.NET` framework version `4.6` and installed [4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851). Then I installed the SDK, and the problem was gone.

Comment: Reverting to version 4 of the .NET Framework, then installing the SDK solved my problem as well. Thanks.

Comment: How exactly do you uninstall 4.6 and install 4.0? I see no option to install framework 4.0 in the Software List and 4.0 refuses to install saying a newer version is already part of the operating system.

Comment: So if I have all Visual Studio components installed I cant install this thing? This (Windows SDK for Windows 7 with .NET Framework 4) is requirement to compile C-code in MATLAB. For this kind of situation I hate windows system.

Comment: I tried this on Windows Server 2012 and managed to somehow uninstall the Windows GUI, resorting to a command line on start up! Luckily I had a backup of that server so just restored from that, but thought that this was worth mentioning.

Comment: *How to uninstall 4.6.1:* Search for or scroll down the list of Microsoft Windows updates to find Update for Microsoft Windows (KB3102467) and click Uninstall. Click Yes to uninstall .NET Framework 4.6.1. After a minute or so you will be prompted to restart the computer. Click Restart Now [source: expta.com](http://www.expta.com/2016/02/how-to-uninstall-net-framework-461.html)

Comment: @bkwdesign this only goes for server 2012.

Comment: This is the solution for Windows 7. The SDK installer error about "pre-release .NET" is a **bug!** When the SDK was released, .NET was at 4.0. The installer does not understand .NET > 4.0, and erroneously reports them as "pre-release". That's why it's necessary to uninstall .NET > 4.0, install .NET 4.0, then install the SDK. After that, .NET 4.x can be reinstalled.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing exactly the same problem mentioned above. After so many attempts the suggestion mentioned in the below link helped

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/6e6c8a17-1666-42fa-9b5b-dfc21845d2f9/error-installing-windows-7-sdk-71-with-vs2008-vs2010-premium-on-win-7-32bit?forum=windowssdk

The steps executed by me are as follows

1. Uninstall Visual C++ and .NET 4.x version
2. Remove register entries corresponding to these installations. I was having Windows 7, but deleted entries as suggested here
3. Restarted Windows
4. Tried installing SDK using web installer
5. This did not work. Later, invoked the SDK installation when the installation screen is still on [with the Installation Error msg] executed debug related msi [you can also install any extracted msi
6. Once after the installation completes, close the Installation error UI [step 5] and reinvoke the installation of SDK.
7. This time, UI screen option would change. Options that you can see is Change, Repair etc. Select Change and complete other component installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had an older version of .NET Framework and the C++ 2010 Redistributable x64 and x86 both. Uninstalling the 2010 allowed me to continue with no issues. I didn't uninstall the older version of .NET, but I did download and install the latest version FIRST.

The only component in the SDK I wanted to install was the Windows Performance Toolkit. I still got the warning at the start of the install. But it went through with anyway.

Maybe that adds a little thought in here...