# How to install pandas in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm

I am trying to install the `pandas` package in pycharm. I get the following error: `unable to find vcvarsall.bat` (i tried to install via the `cmd` but also via the `project interpreter`). I tried to [install](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) WSDK according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534000/python-3-4-windows-10-and-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) but it did not work. I also tried the instructions in the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7n0OwL2jE4). Lastly i tried [downloading](https://github.com/develersrl/gccwinbinaries) the gcc binary according.

None of these worked. Any ideas ? I am using Windows 10, my python version is 3.4.1 and the pip version is 1.5.6 (for 64-bit)

Comment: Have you tried `pip install pandas` ? It should use the wheel and circumvent interpreters. The error you get is related to compiling: "vcvarsall.bat" is part of the compiler in Visual Studio that is necessary to compile the module. Also...pip 1.5.6? The latest pip versions are at version 9 or 10, not 1 ... try upgrading pip first

Comment: @Uvar I get the same error both from cmd and the`pycharm`. How can i upgrade the pip ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` followed by `pip install pandas`, or `python -m pip install pandas`.

Comment: I am receiving this error: ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Answer (score 15):

If you are on latest PyCharm 2018 then follow the below steps to install:

MAC:

Click on **PyCharm** shown on the **Menu** bar -> Click **Preferences** -> Click **Project Interpreter** under your Project -> Click '**+**' -> **search** for 'pandas'/'numpy' (you can specify specific version you want to install) and Click **install** underneath. Now you're done.

Comment: This process is taking forever. Been installing since 45 minutes

Comment: easiest option of all

Answer (score 12):

Open terminal from View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal
type command:

```
pip install pandas
```

Upon successful installation you should see output like so:

```
Successfully installed numpy-1.14.3 pandas-0.23.0 python-dateutil-2.7.3 pytz-2018.4 six-1.11.0
```

Then from File → Settings → Project: *YourProjectName* → Project Interpreter
check that under project interpreter pandas package installed.

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way to do this is install anaconda on your machine.
Then fire up your pycharm >> go to new project >> then you are given with 2 option - one is to select folder and the second one is to select interpreter .

Select interpreter as the directory where you have installed anaconda then go to settings, there you find something **available packages**  then search for the package you wish you install and press **install package**  and you are good to go.

This is the list you will get , just click on the one you want to install and hit **install package**  at the bottom of dialog box.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlAAV.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just write your program, use pandas library.
import pandas -> under pandas you will see red lines.
Hover your mouse there you will see install option just click it and wait for few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I am using PyCharm 2023.3.3.
On the left bottom of pycharm, hover over the buttons, there you can see the option Python Packages. Click on it to open panel, search for Pandas, click on the install button shown.