# Trying to import Pandas into Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pycharm

Error message is suggesting I need to change my PIP version but I don't know how, nor do I know what version I need to change it to.

**Question is:** How do I know what pip version I need and how do I change it?

Comment: Hi! Is there a question?

Comment: You have to share the error message you are getting too. It's not possible to help if you don't post the exact error.

Comment: Question is, how do I know what pip version I need and how do I change it?

Comment: Error occurred was 'Non-zero exit code (1)'.

Proposed solution: Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at ......

Answer (score 0):

General steps are File -> Settings -> Project-> Project Interpreter. Then you click on the plus sign close to the right-hand top corner, finally, you write Pandas in the search field and it is done. After all that you should be able to do `import pandas as pd` Hope I understood your question well.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! This is what I tried but unfortunately I got the error message saying I don't have the correct version of 'pip' installed. But I don't know which version I need or how to change it.

Comment: As mentioned above could you please provide the exact error message?

Comment: Error occurred was 'Non-zero exit code (1)'. 
Proposed solution: Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at ......

Comment: Please read the following:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548875/how-to-install-pandas-in-pycharm