# I cant download module "pandas" on pycharm or CMD

Tags: python, pandas, pip, system-error

managed to download some modules on pycharm it's self but pandas didn't install, so I tried to install on CMD and that replied with this:

C:\WINDOWS\system32>py      -m pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
Using cached pandas-1.1.3.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install pandas in pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45548875/how-to-install-pandas-in-pycharm)

Comment: What error did you receive in PyCharm?

Comment: it says "Error occourred when installing package 'pandas'."

Comment: And here are the detailes: "Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.1.3.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'

DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Adam"

Comment: This shows up when i try to install xlsx.
DEPRECATION: The -b/--build/--build-dir/--build-directory option is deprecated. pip 20.3 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is use the TMPDIR/TEMP/TMP environment variable, possibly combined with --no-clean. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8333.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xlsx (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for xlsx

Answer (score 0):

And if the cache might be corrupted in any way, you could use the --no-cache-dir flag for pip.

See https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
pip install pipwin
```

and then

```
pipwin install pandas
```

Comment: ' C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install pipwin
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. '

Comment: try running cmd in your user and not as admin. Becuase pip might not be in your system path

Comment: Didn't work! The same thing happens. I have tried a lot of methods to install nodules, eventually, through pycharm it worked but maybe in the process of trying all the other methods I have messed something up?

Comment: Did you add pip to your path?

Comment: if not add it to path if is ususally in this folder C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe

Comment: The only app data folder i can find is under 'Default.migrated' and it has a 'Local' folder, a 'Microsoft' folder and a 'windows' folder. but that's it?

Comment: I added pip to my path and still, nothing happens when I type "pip" or "python -m pip" into the command prompt.

Comment: C:\Users\<youruser name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<your python version 38 if you have 3.8>\Scripts\. Most likely this is the path you need to add to PATH. But make sure to check it to see if pip.exe is there.

Answer (score 0):

I had python 3.9 which is not yet supported by these modules I think. I downloaded python 3.8.6 and they download fine. The "pip 'command'" and "python -m 'command'" still don't work but downloading through pycharm works fine.