# python 3 bjoern error compiler with msvc flag cl.exe failed with exit status 2

Tags: python, c++, build, bjoern

I can not compile bjoern for version 3 of python these are the versions I'm using

windows 10
python 3.4
bjoern-py3 -> [https://github.com/isaiah/bjoern-py3][1][1]: https://github.com/isaiah/bjoern-py3
visual c++ -> Visual C++ for Python-9.0

this is the console output

python 2.7
command -> python setup.py build --compiler=msvc

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'bjoern' extension
C:\Users\franciskiko\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWANT_SENDFILE=1 -DWANT_SIGINT_HANDLING=1 -Ihttp-parser -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include /Tchttp-parser\http_parser.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.4\Release\http-parser\http_parser.obj -std=c99 -fno-strict-aliasing -fcommon -fPIC -Wall -g
http_parser.c
http-parser\http_parser.h(206) : warning C4214: nonstandard extension used : bit field types other than int
http-parser\http_parser.h(207) : warning C4214: nonstandard extension used : bit field types other than int
http-parser\http_parser.h(234) : warning C4820: 'http_parser' : '4' bytes padding added after data member 'data'
http-parser\http_parser.c(389) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(389) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(399) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(407) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'const'
http-parser\http_parser.c(408) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'const'
http-parser\http_parser.c(409) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'const'
http-parser\http_parser.c(410) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'const'
http-parser\http_parser.c(411) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'const'
http-parser\http_parser.c(412) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'const'
http-parser\http_parser.c(415) : error C2065: 'header_field_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(415) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(417) : error C2065: 'header_value_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(417) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(419) : error C2065: 'fragment_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(419) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(421) : error C2065: 'query_string_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(421) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(423) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(423) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(429) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(429) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(438) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(449) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(459) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(459) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(476) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(492) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(492) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(504) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(511) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(511) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(516) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(516) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(521) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(521) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(526) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(526) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(532) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(549) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(557) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(567) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(584) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(592) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(606) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(628) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(638) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(660) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(660) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(671) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(671) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(674) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(698) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(708) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(712) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'const'
http-parser\http_parser.c(713) : error C2065: 'matcher' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(713) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
http-parser\http_parser.c(715) : error C2065: 'matcher' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(715) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
http-parser\http_parser.c(752) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(764) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(764) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(764) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(765) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(765) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(765) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(775) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(775) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(775) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(780) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(793) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(798) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(798) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(803) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(803) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(815) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(815) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(815) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(823) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(830) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(841) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(841) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(841) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(849) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(856) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(868) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(869) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(873) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(874) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(880) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(881) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(887) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : error C2065: 'path_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(891) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(895) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(904) : error C2065: 'query_string_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(904) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(904) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(913) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(917) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(923) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(932) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(947) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(947) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(947) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(947) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(947) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(947) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(947) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(947) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant

http-parser\http_parser.c(953) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(953) : error C2065: 'query_string_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(953) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(953) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : error C2065: 'url_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(959) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : error C2065: 'query_string_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : error C2065: 'query_string_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : error C2065: 'query_string_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'size_t' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : warning C4024: 'function through pointer' : different types for formal and actual parameter 3
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : error C2065: 'query_string_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : warning C4047: '=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
http-parser\http_parser.c(960) : warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
http-parser\http_parser.c(966) : error C2065: 'query_string_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(966) : error C2065: 'query_string_mark' : undeclared identifier
http-parser\http_parser.c(966) : fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
error: command 'C:\\Users\\franciskiko\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

python 3.4

command -> python setup.py build --compiler=msvc

```
running build
running build_ext
building 'bjoern' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37534000/windows-10-and-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat ?

Comment: Since different *Python* versions come with different compilers, pick one. Since *bjoem* is for *Py3*, the *Py27* attempt makes no sense. Second, *Py34* is compiled using *VStudio10*.

Comment: I have installed visual studio 10, but it throws me the error error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat, I have looked at the path where visual studio 10 is installed but the file vcvarsall.bat does not exist, it should be in the folder /vc/